# I can't listen events with web3.py on ganache provider

Tags: solidity, remix, web3.py, ganache

I wanted to use the same provider for the Remix IDE and web3.py. So that, I can use the debug features of the remix IDE. I installed ganache and started the provider. I connected the Remix and deployed the contract on remix. then I copied the address of the contract, went to my python code and created the contract.

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
contract_id, compiled_sol = compile_files(["missmatch.sol"], output_values=['abi', 'bin']).popitem()
Missmatch = w3.eth.contract(address='0xb50D3E26E5FB9De8B1D4D69E619B94071e66827a', abi=compiled_sol['abi'])
```

After calling the 'start_committed_bs' function the contract emits the 'request_proof_of_middle' event.
I can see the event on remix
[image: screen shot of remix showing the event]

But I can't retrieve this event with the python code

```
event_filter = Missmatch.events.request_proof_of_middle.createFilter(fromBlock=1)
event = event_filter.get_new_entries()
```

Additionally, this code **was** working with EthereumTesterProvider

Comment: Not sure how good filter support Ganache has. Try using eth_getLogs instead of filters.

Comment: Would you recommend using any other providers?

Comment: I would recommend not to use filters with any provider.

Comment: I tried Foundry instead of Ganache, and it works.